# Fast search algorithm to find Closest Point in a 2 Dimensional Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, search, vector

Im searching for an algorithm which could get me the closest point, in a 2D Array/Matrix, as fast as possible.

Example Matrix:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
________________________
1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
2: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
3: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4: 0 0 0 0 0 X 0 0 0 0 0
5: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

> X = my Point. 1 = Point im searching for.

In this example the "1" on row 6 is the one im searching for.

Right now im scanning the entire array, and calculate for each "1" which is closest to X, but it seems slow to me.

I thought about an searchalgorithm that starts on the fields next to the X, takes circular steps, and breaks when a "1" is found.
Does someone have any idea how to realize this?

Edit: Distance to a point is defined by sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 ). So the distance to the „1“ in row 6 is 2,83.

Edit: To be concrete: this will be used to do a pixelsearch in an image. Startpoint is in the middle, and searching for the closest „correct pixel“.

thanks!

Comment: " starts on the fields next to the X, takes circular steps, and breaks when a "1" is found" you have already formulated the entire algorithm. Now is the time to shape it into code. First step: write the code to find the "X" Second write a loop that scans the circle with a radius of 1 around the "X" If not found => increase the radius

Comment: Define *closest*? Neighbors in how many directions? To find any neighbor quick you need to check closest points first, so scanning current row won't find `1` just above or below.

Comment: is a diagonal step for you equally far/close as a horizontal?

Comment: When you fill the grid just store where all the `1` are and then take your `X` and measure the distance using the distance between 2 points and the shortest is the best. Unless your grid has more `1` than `0` this is the fastest.

Comment: Have you try to store the 1 as X,Y and do simple substraction? Or using the Squareroot((xa-xb)² + (ya-yb)²) if you do diagonal. Like https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Comment: are you responsible for the creation of the grid?

Comment: How large can the matrix get? How sparse is the data in the matrix?

Comment: Are read operations cheap or expensive? e.g. in-memory data structure vs reading from an IoT device over the internet

Comment: I will recommend reading [ask] and [mre], having graphical representation of the array is cute. But real initialisation would have told use how your input is. Perhaps you already use List of Point with already esisting method for the distance : {Chebyschev, Manhattan, Euclidian}
And the expected result would have told us if you used diagonal step. And graphical formated representation are a paint to re write on our side.

Comment: Distance to a point is defined by sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 ). So the distance to the „1“ in row 6 is 2,83.

Comment: That's the Euclidean distance, aka The "ordinary" straight-line. That's an information that you need to  [edit] in the question. You can use the [edit] button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: I‘m not responsible for the grid. To be concrete, this is used to do a pixelsearch. I know the startingpoint, searching for the nearest „correct pixel“.

Comment: May you provide information about your input? Is it a 2dimention array,  `int [,]` with X as separate variable, as X is not a valid int? Or is it an char/string 2D array ?

Comment: The square root method is [`Math.Sqrt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netcore-3.1) for the a² you can simply do `a*a`. You can use [`Math.Abs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netcore-3.1) to avoid negative distance.